# Powershell script pauses after running Perforce Application with cmd until the termination of Perforce Applicaiton

Tags: powershell, automation, scripting, perforce

I am creating a script that will run Perforce and allow the user to login. However, after logging in, the user must manually close Perforce in order for the Powershell script to continue running. I wish to automate that process so that upon logging in, the script will automatically close Perforce itself.

My original code was something like this:

```
$userName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your P4 username'

"p4 -u $userName -p perforceServer:1666" | cmd

"p4 -u$userName -pperforceServer:1666 -cclient files //streamPath @labelName.1.2.3 > fileName.txt" | cmd

$textFile = Get-ChildItem "fileName.txt"

$content = Get-Content $textFile

....
```

Problems arisen from comments:

1. How to execute command in Powershell's shell:
   a) When using `p4 -u $userName -p perforceServer:1666 login`, nothing happens. Script just exits (yes I do have password and login, but prompt is not coming up for some reason).
   b) When using `p4 -u$userName -pperforceServer:1666 -cclient files //streamPath @labelName.1.2.3 > fileName.txt`, the '@' symbol gives me the following error: The splatting operator cannot be used to reference variables in an expression. It can only be used as an argument to the command (which is what I am doing) using the single quote (when doing so the error goes away, but my command does not execute properly as in it does not pull from the stream (fileName.txt is empty).
2. How to know when user has successfully logged in?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why does cmd.exe need to be involved at all? (PowerShell is a shell, after all, and one of the purposes of a shell is to execute programs.)

Comment: Why don't you just have the script run the Perforce command (via the `p4` CLI, not `p4v`) in the shell?  By default, Perforce will automatically prompt you for a login (if needed) and then execute the command, all in the same client process.

Comment: Thank you for the responses! @Bill_Stewart The issue that I am now experiencing is that the script will execute the following codes before the user has properly logged in. I am having trouble figuring out how to ensure that the user has already logged in before the rest of the code are executed. Thanks!

Comment: @Samwise How do I execute p4 as opposed to p4v? I tried `p4 -u $userName -p perforceServer:1666` but it doesn't seem to do anything (password prompt does not pop up). Thanks!

Comment: To get the password prompt:  
p4 -u $userName -p perforceServer:1666 login

Comment: Does the script need to run an actual Perforce command, or is it just logging in and not doing anything else in Perforce?  If it needs to run a command, run *that command* (sync, edit, submit, etc) and the login will happen automatically if needed.  If you *just* need to login then run the “login” command.

Comment: @JBrown Still no password prompt with login. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: If `p4 login` doesn't prompt you for a password, you don't have a password set and don't need to login at all.  Sounds like you may be trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist.  :)  My advice is to just continue with writing your script as if you've already solved this part, and if you hit a "login required" error, please update your question to include that error message and the code in your script that provoked it.

Comment: @Samwise Yes, I probably should've clarified, I do run actual perforce commands after. I am pulling from a stream. And the reason I am piping it to cmd is because I could not figure out how to execute that command thru powershell's shell. Currently my code is `"p4 -u$userName -pperforceServer:1666 -cclient files //streamPath @labelName.1.2.3 > fileName.txt" | cmd` The @ is what was causing me issues. I tried escaping the @ with backticks, but no avail. Also, in order to do what you suggested, would I need to be enabled by 'p4 protect'? This would not be possible for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Samwise I do have a password, and login as running it thru cmd prompts me for the password. There is no error message, simply nothing happens. The code is this `p4 -u $userName -p perforceServer:1666 login`. Thanks!

Comment: It prompts you for the password, but also nothing happens?  Please update your original post to include the code you're running and the exact output of running that code; it's hard to piece together from fragments spread across comments.

Answer (score 1):

Piping the p4 command to `cmd` makes it difficult to interact with the command, since `cmd` isn't going to spawn an interactive session.  You should be able to simply do the interaction within Powershell:

```
$userName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your P4 username'
p4 -u $userName -p perforceServer:1666 login
$content = p4 -u $userName -p perforceServer:1666 files //streamPath/...@labelName.1.2.3
```

Since the command will write its output to stdout, writing it to a file and then reading it back in from the file is an unnecessary level of indirection; you can just assign it directly to `$content`.

For the case of a command where you weren't trying to redirect the output, you could simply run the command and then allow the auto-login functionality to handle authentication:

```
PS C:\perforce\test> $userName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your P4 username'
Input your P4 username: bob
PS C:\perforce\test> p4 -u $userName sync -m1
Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset.
Attempting login for user 'bob' against server 'rsh:p4d.exe -i -r "c:\Perforce\test\.p4root"'
Enter password:
User bob logged in.
//stream/child_stream/lock/foo#2 - added as c:\Perforce\test\lock\foo
```

but in the case of your script this isn't suitable because you don't want `$content` to capture the login prompt.

To check the login status of the user, you can use `p4 login -s`:

```
PS C:\perforce\test> p4 -u $userName login -s
User bob ticket expires in 11 hours 54 minutes.
PS C:\perforce\test> p4 -u $userName -Ztag login -s
... User bob
... TicketExpiration 42845

PS C:\perforce\test> p4 -u $userName logout
User bob logged out.
PS C:\perforce\test> p4 -u $userName -Ztag login -s
Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset.
```

Combining `-Ztag` and `-F` can give you an easily-parseable string that you specify the format of, eg:

```
PS C:\perforce\test> p4 -u $userName -Ztag -F "[SUCCESS: %TicketExpiration%|ERROR]" login -s
ERROR
PS C:\perforce\test> p4 -u $userName login
Enter password:
User bob logged in.
PS C:\perforce\test> p4 -u $userName -Ztag -F "[SUCCESS: %TicketExpiration%|ERROR]" login -s
SUCCESS: 43199
```

Comment: Hi @Samwise I appreciate the response! It was very helpful, however, I am still having trouble with this line: `$content = p4 -u $userName -p perforceServer:1666 files //streamPath/...@labelName.1.2.3`. I get the following error: Access for user '$userName' has not been enabled by 'p4 protect'. Thanks!

Comment: That sounds like Powershell isn't expanding the variable and is passing the literal string `$userName`.  Not sure why that would be, as I haven't used Powershell other than the example given in this answer (and variable expansion seemed to work fine there).  Maybe something to do with how the script is being invoked?

Comment: Hi @Samwise My apologies. I meant the it is not recognizing my username as being enabled by p4 protect, not that it is passing in the literal string $userName. I'm not sure why this error comes out with PowerShell, and works fine with Cmd. Thanks!

Comment: It's either a different username or a different server address.  If you paste the exact commands you're running in both shells and the exact output I might be able to help spot the typo.